# Finding limit of a two-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Which path should be used to find
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2-x}$$

Comment: If the limit exists,then whatever 'path' you follow,you will get to the same answer

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates

$$\frac{r^3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2-r\cos\theta}=\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r-\cos\theta}.$$

Then if $\cos\theta\ne0$, the function tends to $0$ with $r$ along all radial lines (provided $r<\cos\theta$). And if $\cos\theta=0$, the expression is exactly $0$.

But near the curve

$$r=\cos\theta,$$

(a circle through the origin) the function is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

Denominator vanishes when $x^{2}+y^{2}=x$. This gives a hint that you should make the denominator small compared to the numerator. Take  $y =\sqrt {x+x^{3}-x^{2}}$ so that $x^{2}+y^{2}-x=x^{3}$ You  can see that the limit (through positive $x$) is $\infty$.